# How to define an array of integers in a declare-styleable?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources, typed-arrays, declare-styleable

I'm implementing my own `<declare-styleable>` for a custom View (following the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)). I'd like to be able to specify an array of integers as one of the possible XML attributes. How do I:

1. Specify the integer array as an XML attribute in `attrs.xml`?
2. Get it from the [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html) after calling `obtainStyledAttributes()` in my custom View?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. You can declare it as a reference.

   ```
   <declare-styleable name="MyView">
       <attr name="array" format="reference"/>
   </declare-styleable>
   ```
2. It looks like `TypeArray` hasn't `getIntArray` method so you have to get it directly from the resources.

   ```
   final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView);
   final int id = array.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyView_array, 0);

   if (id != 0) {
       final int[] values = getResources().getIntArray(id);
   }

   array.recycle()
   ```

Comment: Don't forget to call array.recycle() after using a TypedArray. That would be after line 2.

Comment: I get always 0. Anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to add comments, just want to share the kotlin way, where the extension function handles recycle() call itself.

```
context.withStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView, defStyleAttr) { 
    val resourceId = getResourceId(R.styleable.MyView_array, 0) 
}
```